# Enable or disable asp.net STS by web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, wif

Can I have a switch in web.config for enabling or disabling the STS? e.g. 
In app setting
if it is <add key="siteMode" value="public">, users do not need to login.
if it is <add key="siteMode" value="staff">, users need to provide their login info

Comment: +1 - Interesting question, I am interested in what the answer is...

Comment: sorry my typing error, I have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

That would be easily possible if your login page just creates the identity automatically without requiring users to login in the "public" mode. This involves the SessionAuthenticationModule:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2012/09/forms-authentication-revisited.html

Comment: Thanks your reply! I have read your article, but I still do not know how to do it. The article is still using Form authentication, but my site has already implemented STS (SessionAuthenticationModule instead of the form).  Do you have more details about it?

Comment: The article doesn't use forms auth. Starting from the middle, I show how to create identities for the session auth module. Just read that part again.